# By what medium is information about electric field propagation communicated?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields

After watching the recent Veritasium video on electricity, I, like many other people was skeptical. I got a 75m length of copper wire, and an oscilloscope, and ran the experiment myself. My results agreed with his, which brought up an interesting question.

Consider the following thought experiment: We have a circuit that is two light years long, and of negligible width. On the bottom middle of the circuit, there is a battery and a switch. Opposite from these on the top of the circuit there is a lightbulb. Also we can assume the circuit is made of superconductor so resistance is negligible. [image]

One clock is kept at the switch, and the other is sent out to the far end of the circuit. The clocks are relativistically adjusted before departure so that when the clocks are one light year apart and moving at 0m/s relative to each other, they will each go off at the exact same time. When the clocks go off, the switch is flipped and simultaneously, a portion of the wire is cut on the edge of the circuit so that no(or a non-measurable amount) of electrons will be able to move through the circuit.

According to my experimental results, when the switch is flipped, the light will turn on(in width/c seconds but lets just call it instant). My question is, for how long will the light bulb remain on, and what particles mediate the interaction that tells the circuit it can no longer conduct electricity.

Veritasium Videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oI_X2cMHNe0&t=13s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHIhgxav9LY&t=139s

Comment: Is it really best to analyze it in terms of particles, rather than electromagnetic fields?